# Image not rendering in my Admin application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I am creating a admin application where i want to display uploaded images of product stored in database. I have uploaded images as an object id in MongoDB. But the image container in admin app displays the number of images stored in database. But the images are not displayed. I tried using absolute URL too but that doesnot work either.

Here is my code to upload images:

```
{productPictures.length > 0
          ? productPictures.map((pic, index) => (
              <div key={index}>{pic.name}</div>
            ))
          : null}
        <input
          type="file"
          name="productPictures"
          onChange={handleProductPictures}
        />
```

Here is the code to display images:

```
<label className="key">Product Pictures</label>
            <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
              {productDetails.productPictures.map((picture) => (
                <div className="productImgContainer">
                  <img src={generatePublicUrl(picture.img)} alt="" />
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
```

Generate URL function looks like this:

```
const api ='http://localhost:2000/'
// const api = 'http://192.168.0.104:2000/'
const generatePublicUrl = (fileName) => {
    return `http://localhost:2000/src/uploads/products/${fileName}`;
}
export {
    api,
    generatePublicUrl
};
```

Function to save product in database:

```
const createProduct= (req, res) => {
  const { name, price, description, category, quantity, createdBy } = req.body;
  let productPictures = [];

  if (req.files.length > 0) {
    productPictures = req.files.map((file) => {
      return { img: file.location };
    });
  }

  const product = new Product({
    name: name,
    slug: slugify(name),
    price,
    quantity,
    description,
    productPictures,
    category,
    createdBy: req.user._id,
  });

  product.save((error, product) => {
    if (error) return res.status(400).json({ error });
    if (product) {
      res.status(201).json({ product, files: req.files });
    }
  });
        
}
```

The uploaded images in program looks like this:
[Open image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yux2F.png)

But the page displays blank area and filename shows undefined when inspected.
[Open image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5mlW.png)

Comment: Can you share an example of `productDetails.productPictures`

Comment: I would start to debug this at the beginning. So does each of the files in `req.files` have a location property and is it what you expect it to be?? What library do you use for uploads?

Comment: @Molda i am using Multer library to upload files. req.files have src/uploads/products as location property. I have saved images inside that directory but the images are not being fetched and rendered.

Comment: @Mohammednaji you mean you want those uploaded images names?

Comment: @niteshraj so you are saying that the productPictures object before you save it to db looks like this `[{ img: 'src/uploads/products' }, ...]` ?? So where do you same the filenames (xxx.jpeg)?? According to the documentation(which you should have read) the file has these props `filename/destination/path/etc.` and yet you decided to use `location` which is **not even mentioned** in the docs, why?? [Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#user-content-file-information)

Comment: I want what inside the object

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are trying to add a `non-public path` to the source.
you need to add the files to the `public` folder so you can call assets using the path , otherwise you can import the `images` and then add them to the `src` attribute

Edit 1:

```
return `http://localhost:2000/src/uploads/products/${fileName}`;
```

this will not work , you can't access what inside the src
the only folder you can access it is the `public` folder